# debounceTime on FormControl causes function that runs on ENTER not to have the updated value

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have

```
public model;
public control = new FormControl('');

control.valueChanges.debounceTime(300).subscribe((value) => {
  this.model = value;
});

myFunc() {
  console.log(this.model);
}
```

Then:

```
<input [formControl]="control" (keydown.enter)="myFunc()">
```

As you can see `myFunc` runs on ENTER so when I press it without waiting `300ms`, I only get a substring of the `this.model` since the `valueChanges` subscription haven't updated the model yet.

How can I make sure that when I press enter, `this.model` is fully updated with what's written in the input?

Comment: why do you use debounce just to assign value to `this.model`?

Comment: @Mani Because API calls shouldn't be called for each letter.

Comment: do you call API from subscribe method or when you press enter?

Comment: Just do the api call in valueChanges.